# How to format number to currency but don't show the symbol?

Tags: php

What i'm trying to achieve is converting a number to currency format to add decimals and commas whenever needed , but i don't want it to show the currency symbol.

I used to use number_format but that's depreciated in favor of the newer function.

I tried this:

```
$val = "23";
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'en', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
// i tried the following 
$num = numfmt_format_currency($fmt, $val); // omitted the 3rd parameter but caused error 
$num = numfmt_format_currency($fmt, $val,null); // tried to null or blank the 3rd param but im getting a weird symbol / prefix
```

[image]

EDIT: correction, i meant money_format is depreciated, not number_format . sorry

Comment: Can't you just use `numfmt_format` instead of `numfmt_format_currency`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep it easy MultiSuperFreaks answer is the most common. The function `number_format` is not deprecated in any way.

If you want to use the intl extension and the `NumberFormatter` class, you can go like ...

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_GB', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
var_dump($formatter->format(23)); // string(5) "23.00"
```

Just do not use the `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` type. Instead use the `NumberFormatter::DECIMAL` type when instanciating the `NumberFormatter` class and then set the attribute for minimal 2 fraction digits.

Answer (score 1):

I all you want is to add two decimals to every number, you can use `number_format($val, 2)` to get a formatted number without any symbol.

EDIT: Number format in the standard PHP library is not deprecated (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace for doing it, just like in the following example:

```
$string = '@15.32'; 
$pattern = '/([^0-9]*)(\d*)(.*)/'; 
$replacement = '${2}${3}'; 
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

The output will be: 15:32. The idea is that everything up to the first number will be discarded, leaving you with all the rest. So in your example, only the number will stay.